# PHP: json_encode() SyntaxError if use of include_once()

Tags: php, ajax, json

REMARK: **USING XAMPP**
On PHP I'm using `json_encode()` to return data to a JS/JQuery ajax request.

The ajax call from .js:

```
$.ajax({url: "/sys/search_rf/functions.php" ,
    async: false, // wait for reponse
    type: "post",
    data: { id: $('#id').val(),
            status: $('#status').val(),
            token: cToken } ,
    success: function(jsonResponse,status){ // POST success
        console.log(jsonResponse);
    jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
            [...]
        }
```

It works just fine until I `require_once()` another .php in functions.php.

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/searches.php'); // -> ../searches.php
```

Output debug:
[image: json_encode outputs]

None of the included PHP echoes/print anything at all, except the function which returns the `json_encode()`.

So then, I edited searches.php and left it like this (debugging purpose):

```
<?php

?>
```

So I'm 100% sure nothing is echoing, and I kept:

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/searches.php'); // -> ../searches.php
```

in functions.php, which responds to ajax request.

But the error stills:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

And if I comment it, there will be no errors!

```
// require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/searches.php'); // -> ../searches.php
```

I suppose every time I `require_once()` it 'echoes' something. I don't really know.

---

I also checkd all EOL/Encoding of all files.
All in Unix Format encoded in UTF-8.

---

**This workaround will do, but I think it's not the proper solution:**

```
jsonData = JSON.parse( jsonResponse.trim() );
```

.trim()

Comment: The error says everything, you're passing some characters to json response. Try removing closing php tags ?> and make sure nothing is printed before the response. You have some weird ??? that are causing this problem, so the json_encode cannot actually encode the string because it's not valid json string.

Comment: use ob_start/ob_end_clean to be sure that nobody write here)

Comment: Make sure your searches.php exists and turn off your error reporting. May be you get some errors in including the file or searches.php spits some errors or warnings.

Comment: `?>` removing should solve the issue... There are only pair questionmarks(cr/lf?) in response

Comment: tried both. `ob_start();/ob_end_clean();` and removing the `?>`. It ONLY WORKS if I do not `require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/searches.php');` even though it has nothing on it.

Comment: but why dirname twice? this might be the issue

Comment: it is the parent directory: `require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/searches.php'); // -> ../searches.php`

Comment: even using `require_once("D:\full\path\to\searches.php");` the error stills occur!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove closing php tag and all spaces before opening php tag. Also check if you use UTF-8 without BOM in your file.

Comment: tried both. ob_start();/ob_end_clean(); and removing the ?>. It ONLY WORKS if I do not require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/searches.php'); even though it has nothing on it.

Comment: Can you post somewhere json code,that you get and can't parse and the other you can?
http://pastebin.com/ would be ok.

Comment: It is in the image attached to the post. See, if i copy/paste from debug to notepad they will look exactly the same! But this app JSONedit seems to catch the dirty chars as '??'

Comment: I did tried it, But if I don't parse it will be a simple string

Comment: Just tried. All the same. It seems like the problem is issuing the `include_once()` command, not the included file itself.

Comment: It has some sensitive data and it is commented in Portuguese. I'll do some edits on it then I will post on paste.bin

Comment: Check if you use UTF-8 without BOM in your file.

Comment: that worked! UTF-8 without BOM. thanks! Post it as a answer so I can check it as solution.