# php special character at end of every page cause ajax response error

Tags: php, ajax, special-characters

I have strange problem in every PHP page, at end of every response there is some special character, that is not related to PHP script, I test it with just `<?php phpinfo();?>` page that is there.

They are like this
�

But that is not in 404 static page response, I think that is related to php config over version or, not Apache config, but I can’t find what cause this.

Bad situation is that it cause every AJAX/Json response fails, because change structure of response data by adding special character at end of every response

What cause this problem and how can solve it?

Comment: so , i should remove bom from php.ini file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: json\_encode() SyntaxError if use of include\_once()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897923/php-json-encode-syntaxerror-if-use-of-include-once)

Comment: i used this command wget --header="accept-encoding: gzip" http://onesite.com and see : ^_�^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ at end of every response

Comment: Debian wheezy 7.5, but i need it because OJS(http://pkp.sfu.ca/ojs/) don't work correctly without it

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 14 Jun 2014 06:16:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u9
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 14 Jun 2014 06:16:02 +0000
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
ETag: "1402726562"
Content-Language: en
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/223462/100013), the issue is problems with `mod_gzip`:

> The problem is being caused by mod_gzip and the fact that you do not
>   have a final newline in your files. The newline problem is caused by
>   serving Windows-encoded files on a Unix system.

This might be connected to line ending differences between Windows & Unix machines. I actually answered [a similar question earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166800/php-problems-when-transfering-code-from-windows-to-os-x/24167027#24167027). Specifically:

> Different operating systems use different characters to mark the end
>   of line:
>
> - Unix / Linux / OS X uses LF (line feed, '\n', 0x0A)
> - Macs prior to OS X use CR (carriage return, '\r', 0x0D)
> - Windows / DOS uses CR+LF (carriage return followed by line feed, '\r\n', 0x0D0A)

If you are on a Linux server you can install the [`dos2unix` tool](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) to convert the PHP files in question to properly formatted Linux text files.

If you are on Ubuntu—for example—just run this command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

Then you can run it like this on a file:

```
dos2unix some_kind_of_file.php
```

Which would take `some_kind_of_file.php` and convert it in place from Windows line endings to Unix line endings. More details [here](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/dos2unix-removing-hidden-windows-characters-from-files/).

Comment: JakeGould, that is in all page , i used this command : find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} {} \; to convert all files to unix format but this don't work

Comment: i used this command wget --header="accept-encoding: gzip" http://onesite.com and see : ^_�^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ at end of every response